# The sum of two consecutive even integers is 404. Find the double of the first.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, word-problem

This exercise is giving me trouble. Could you please help me?

"The sum of two consecutive even integers is 404. Find the double of the first."

let be the first even number $x$

the secound $x+2$

The equation would be:

$x+x+2=404$

When solving the equation it gives me: $x=201$

So the first number would be $201$ and the second $203$

But that number is not even. So I don't know if is the exercise is ill-posed or if I just need to answer that there a not two even that their sum is $404$.

Thanks for helping.

Comment: It seems ill-posed to me....

Comment: Even if there were a solution , "first" is a bad formulation. Better would be "smaller".

Comment: Since it is required to give the concrete solution and not just to check whether there is one , the exercise is clearly ill-posed since there is no such solution.

Comment: The problem is perhaps ill-posed, but as such you have to conclude there is no solution.

Comment: The sum of 2 consecutive even numbers can not be a multiple of 4. So you can show that there is no solution to the given condition.

Comment: thanks everyone

Answer (score 0):

If the sum of an odd real number and an odd imaginary number can be considered even, then one solution is $\quad \big((201-i), (203+i)\big)$.